# How do i have Apache to do further handling of the error status set within the PHP script?

Tags: php, header, apache2, status, errordocument

My environment is: shared hosting with PHP 5.2 installed as apache2handler

I have ErrorDocuments configured:

```
ErrorDocument 404 "Simply Not Found"
# OR
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/fancy-not-found.php
# both variants works as expected
```

However, most simple example from PHP [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) doesnt want to cooperate with Apache2 and perform compliant error handling:

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
die(); /* results in empty page */
/* OR */
die('Failed');  /* reports failure */
?>
```

How to amend this code to trigger specified error and make Apache sort it out?

Comment: I think I have a similar problem and I think if there's an answer it will apply to both of us. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253083/displaying-custom-error-page-in-php-for-errors-which-cant-be-caught-by-set-error

Comment: Yes, the same problem in the essence. However, i do not like idea about abandoning Apache in favour of PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is broken and this question proven to be unanswerable

---

Currently, my findings are:

- seen desired behavior produced with mod_perl, which have fully featured response API.
- mod_php is badly designed and is using apache1-style handler instead of apache2 filter(s), effectively disabling ability to pass control back to httpd.
- most recommended solution is to drop apache features and re-implement all of the handling logic using PHP scripts.